# 0 Learnable parameters in Lstmcell pytorch

Tags: pytorch, lstm

[Does anyone know what could be the reason for 0 learnable parameters in lstm cells][1]

Comment: Do you expect us to guess the solution based on a one-line question? Please provide details on what is really going on: how is the layer initialized, your training loop, and the parameter update...

Comment: I apologise, noob mistake. i wil describe the problem at a greater length within a few day.  A possible answer is presented.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this may be the case in your code is because you have freezed the params in your LSTM as their required grad is False.

Or the params in your LSTM may not be calculating gradients as they could have been detached.

Therefore there will be 0 learnable parameters in this case.

Sarthak Jain